# Integrating grobid with tika and solr

Tags: solr, apache-tika, grobid

I'm using Solr to index journal articles.  Using the out-of-the-box configuration, it indexed the text of the documents, but I'm looking to use Grobid to pull out the authors, title, affiliations, etc.  I got grobid up and running as a service.

I added

> `<str name="tika.config">/path/to/tika-config.xml</str>`

to the requestHandler for /update/extract in solrconfig.xml

The tika-config looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<properties>
  <parsers>
    <parser class="org.apache.tika.parser.journal.JournalParser">
      <mime>application/pdf</mime>
    </parser>
  </parsers>
</properties>
```

I'm getting a ClassNotFound exception when I try to import a document, but can't figure out where to set the classpath to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned on the Solr user's list, the latest version of Solr (6.0.0) is using a version of Tika (1.7) that predates the addition of grobid (which came in in Tika 1.11) [permalink](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.lucene.solr.user/120922).  To follow the upgrade to Tika 1.13, see [SOLR-8981](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-8981)